# How do you set PGSTAT_STAT_INTERVAL using postgres docker image?

Tags: postgresql, docker

My overall goal is to count the number of queries my ETL process is making to my postgres DB to prevent N-query issues. I'm successfully counting transactions to foo DB using the following statement:

```sql
SELECT sum(xact_commit+xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = 'foo'
```

In order to count the number of transactions my ETL process makes, I execute the above before and after the ETL process and calculate the difference. The issue is I have to sleep for 500ms in order for this to work since [PGSTAT_STAT_INTERVAL defaults to 500ms](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS). I'd like to decrease that number to 100ms so that I'm not adding lag to each test that requires this assertion.

The postgres docs say "500 ms unless altered while building the server" so I've attempted to increase this to 1000ms in my docker compose to see if the change takes affect:

```yaml
  foo-db:
    image: postgres:13
    command: ["PGSTAT_STAT_INTERVAL=1000", "postgres", "-c", "log_statement=mod"]
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=bar
      - PGSTAT_STAT_INTERVAL=1000
```

From some crude testing this does not appear to be working. How do I set PGSTAT_STAT_INTERVAL in my docker compose?